# Mysql select distinct values from a series

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, distinct

I have a mysql table like

```
 Speed   Lat  Lon       TimeStamp
  12      1    22    2012-02-03 00:00:05
  13      2    23    2012-02-03 00:00:10
  0       3    24    2012-02-03 00:00:15
  0       3    24    2012-02-03 00:00:20
  14      4    25    2012-02-03 00:00:25
  0       5    26    2012-02-03 00:00:30
  0       5    26    2012-02-03 00:00:35
  0       5    26    2012-02-03 00:00:40
  5       6    27    2012-02-03 00:00:45
  0       6    27    2012-02-03 00:00:50
```

I need to select (all the records with speed != 0) + (one record from a series of records where speed == 0 ).
ie i will be expecting something like

```
 Speed  Lat1  Lat2     Timestamp
  12      1    22    2012-02-03 00:00:05
  13      2    23    2012-02-03 00:00:10
  0       3    24    2012-02-03 00:00:15
  14      4    25    2012-02-03 00:00:25
  0       5    26    2012-02-03 00:00:30
  5       6    27    2012-02-03 00:00:45
  0       6    27    2012-02-03 00:00:45
```

I tried using distinct and group by for different columns.. Not working..
Please help me with a query..

Edited:

I have added time stamp field and one more record which i use for ORDER BY
If i am using a group by with Lat,Lon last record wont be selected. But i need it. 
(The thing is if the vehicle comes back to the same latitude and longitude in another time whether it is moving or Idle)
Any help will be appreciated..

Comment: Why isn't `DISTINCT` working? It will give you the desired result with this example. Please give an example where `DISTINCT` doesn't do the trick.

Comment: can you update the examples?

Comment: `distinct` does work with the sample test data given, but would not work if the test data included rows (0, 3, 24) & (0, 4, 25) rather than (0, 3, 24) & (0, 3, 24). The OP does not state clearly the problem  domain. If (as one might assume) these rows are sequential and describe the speed and position of a moving object then it might also be safe to assume that sequential rows with a speed of 0 will maintain the same  position. This is an assumption though, and if it were the case merely poses the problem to one of 'how do I get these rows in the correct order'

Comment: @lintu: You say you have "a series of records" but I see no column that can be used for ordering.

Comment: @ypercube .. Series of same values(when speed is 0).. In the example there are two series.
My mistake if it mislead u..

Comment: You have not mislead me. I still see no series. Table are not ordered. Results may be returned in whatever order the DBMS may decide (and not in the same order always). Unless you provide an `ORDER BY`. You seem to assume otherwise.

Comment: If the only criterion is to show only distinct rows (when speed is 0), then Kaf's query is a good answer.

Comment: Ok thing is i use an ORDER BY time stamp..

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you want if you have *speed non zero but duplicate rows* (ie; two rows of 13,      2,    23) ? Without considering above point, you can get the expected results using a `UNION` [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cfc9d7/8) (thanks @echo_me for the fiddle)

```
Select Speed , lat as Lat1 , Lon as Lon1 
From Table1 where speed <> 0
UNION
Select Speed , lat as Lat1 , Lon as Lon1 
From Table1 where speed = 0
Order by lat1
```

***Or*** if you want duplicated non zero records you could `UINON ALL` with Grouped Zero records [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/57d63/2)

```
Select Speed , lat as Lat1 , Lon as Lon1 
From Table1 where speed <> 0
UNION ALL
Select Speed , lat as Lat1 , Lon as Lon1 
From Table1 where speed = 0
Group by speed,lat1,lon1
Order by lat1
```

Comment: This is almost identical to `SELECT DISTINCT Speed , lat as Lat1 , Lon as Lon1 from Table1`. The only difference would be your query wouldn't include rows where `speed` was NULL (if there were ones).

Comment: @AndriyM: OP said he tried using `DISTINCT` and `Group By`, Without seen all his data, this is a different approach, yes I understand `UNION` does what `DISTINCT` does after all...

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
   SELECT Speed , lat as Lat1 , Lon as Lon1 
   FROM Table1
   GROUP BY Lat
```

[**SQL DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cfc9d7/4)